# MySQL table JOIN with LIKE without adding another ID column

Tags: mysql

I have two tables named **"regions"** and **"city_list"**:

```
REGIONS TABLE:
r_id      r_code        r_name
1         REGION I      Ilocos Region
2         REGION II     Cagayan Valley
3         REGION III    Central Luzon
4         REGION IV-A   CALABARZON
5         REGION IV-B   MIMAROPA

CITY_LIST TABLE:

city_id   city_name        city_region
32        Catbalogan       REGION VIII (Eastern Visayas)
33        Cauayan          REGION II (Cagayan Valley)
34        Cavite City      REGION IV-A (CALABARZON)
35        Cebu City        REGION VII (Central Visayas)
87        City of Naga     REGION VII (Central Visayas)
```

I want to reference the regions table when a user selects a city name from the **city_list** table. For example:

User selects **"Cauauyan"** from a drop-down list, the server returns the region code which is the **"r_code"** column from the Regions table.

Can I use a JOIN statement with LIKE without adding a column for a region ID in the **city_list** table? Is it possible to get the value in city_region like "REGION II" without the "(Cagayan Valley)" and use that value to get r_id in the REGIONS table?

Comment: Here u r already storing region in city_list table with name city_region then why join is required..please elaborate your actual requirement little bit more.

Comment: Why you don't used from `r_id` in city table, because now your `CITY_LIST` table don't need any data from regions during selection.

Comment: Looks like you have the region name and not the I'd in the cities list. Not relational but anyway - you can join to the regions table and get the region I'd that way. Just remember to add an index on the city_region field for performance.

Comment: Yes. The region name is already in the city_list table but I want to get the ID of the region for that city. Can I use concat on the city_region column to get for example just "REGION II" and use a WHERE statement to get the region ID?

Comment: @MobasherFasihy Yes. That would be much easier to deal with. I'm currently redesigning the tables from this old app. I just wanted to know if there was a possible solution to the question given the current tables.

Comment: So its good to remove the bad point and designs of your system. But you can do this by using something like `LIKE` or `STRCMP`

Comment: why do you want to use the `r_code` column from the `regions` table? you already have the perfect scenario. If you want the region for a particular city its already contained in `city_region` . just add `city_region` to your query. For `Cauauyan` you will get `REGION II (Cagayan Valley)` you may need to strip the `(Cagayan Valley)` out but thats easy

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT r.r_id 
FROM REGIONS r
WHERE r.`r_code` IN(
SELECT LEFT(`CITY_LIST`.`city_region`,INSTR(`CITY_LIST`.`city_region`,"(")-1) AS Region_id FROM `CITY_LIST`);
```

Comment: @johnxbogart Did u check my answer if its giving the output?